# Facebook API integration into CMS - Questions regarding App Domains, Redirect URLs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I'm at the planning stages of adding some functionality to a CMS. Kind of new to the Graph API, so excuse any blatant ignorance.

At any given time, there are more than 1000 sites/domains that use the system. The plan is to create a single app, with an APP ID, and secret - and then have the users authenticate themselves.

What I'm having trouble grasping is the required entries for app domains, and OAuth redirect URIs on the app dashboard. Since many domains will be using the app, how is that handled? I found a somewhat related post here:
[Facebook API key for an open source CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596194/facebook-api-key-for-an-open-source-cms)

Someone suggested the creation of a loopback server to handle the requests. So would be the best method to create a separate domain on the system, and funnel everything through that..something like facebook.mysite.com ?

Comment: With that approach, you will only be able to use the API server-side – using it client-side with the JS SDK is out of the question then.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in your case, you'll either want to use a shared endpoint (with increased security) which provides some method for 'sibling' domains to share state, or you'll want to use separate apps per domain.

Given that the user will be asked to provide information to a named app, using separate apps, with more contextual names than 'CMS SSO Provider' might be the right move.

Comment: Cool. I don't think separate apps for each of our customers will be an option. Many are not tech savvy and would be unable to complete the app building process (or someone here *me* would have to create an app for each domain that's created on the system). Which is why I was considering the one app that I could seamlessly integrate into the framework. This points me in the right direction though. Thx.

Comment: In case anyone has this similar question in the future. I hosted a callback page on our main domain. www.pretendcompanyname.com/auth_callback.aspx
When generating the oauth request, I'm passing the callback a parameter via query string (basically a cache key that expires in a short period of time) - so I can cache / retrieve the token from system cache. If that makes any sense